# UnityEngine.Windows.Speech及びUnityEngine.Windows.Speech.DictationRecognizerのアンドロイド版

Tags: android, unity3d, azure

[こちら](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mr-azure-301)を参考に翻訳システムをアンドロイド上で使ってみようとしているのですが、unityからbuildする際に、下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Windows' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Windows' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Windows' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

他にもエラーがありますが、これらが解決すればなくなるような気がします。
何か方法はあるでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 名前からしてWindows以外では動作しないと思われます。Android自身の機能を使うこれらの記事で代替するのでは？ [FantomPlugin v1.18 (Unity × Android)](https://booth.pm/ja/items/1556439), [AndroidのSpeechRecognizerをネイティブプラグイン化してUnityで使う](http://edom18.hateblo.jp/entry/2018/03/21/175104)

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。